# What is the best package in R to plot city maps and put points on it?

Tags: r, geolocation, maps

That's the question, best R package to plot city maps and geolocate stuff.

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Maybe I wasn't too clear, but I mean urban city maps, where you can see its streets, neighborhoods etc.

Comment: How about looking at `leaflet`?

Comment: there is also a package for *openstreetmap*: `osmar` (https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/eugster-schlesinger.pdf)

Comment: And `googleway` for accessing [google streetview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39198783/5977215)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visible streets and roads, you can use a package named 'ggmap' and a function named qmap() within it.

Package named 'maps'. Install that and use map.cities() function.
You can also try rMaps, this you will find under github. Its still under development. You can work with this in R or RStudio.